# Can not load the module on HotTowel SPA

Tags: javascript, amd, durandal, hottowel

I have a SPA project using John Papa's great HotTowel.

I have a `listservice` module in the `services` folder and function is like:

```
define(['services/logger', 'models/businessobject', 'config'],
    function (logger, businessobject, config) {
        ...
    }
```

Also I have a `businessobject` module in the `models` folder. But when I'm running the app in the `listservice` module the value of the parameter `businessobject` is null.

Is there anything I miss do to tell `RequireJS` or `Durandal/Amd` that the `businessobject` module is there?

The content of `businessobject.js` is like:

```
define(['services/logger'],
function(logger) {
    var BusinessObject = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable();
        self.typeId = ko.observable();
        self.descriptor = ko.observable();
        self.isNullo = false;
        return self;
    };

    return BusinessObject;
}
```

Also, using Firebug, I've checked that the `businessobject` module is loaded to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BusinessObject is not being instantiated in any way.  If you are trying to use it to expose various models than you can do so like this -

```
define([], function() {

    var businessModels = {
         businessObject: businessObject
    };
    return businessModels;

    function businessObject(id, typeid, descriptor, isNullo) {       
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(id);
        self.typeId = ko.observable(typeid);
        self.descriptor = ko.observable(descriptor);
        self.isNullo = isnullo;
    }
```

and then from your listservice

```
var myObj = new BusinessObject.businessObject(1, 2, 'my obj', false);
```

Or if you just want to have a single module for each model, which seems a bit bulky but surely can be done, you can leave your code as-is and instantiate it normally -

```
var myObj = new BusinessObject();
```